# There are two models that have the same least validation loss value but have that value at different epoch. Which one is better?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

There are two models that have same structure and learn same dataset.

And those models record the same least validation loss value.

The difference is like below.

1. The First model doesn't have regularization and stops learning at epoch 15(this epoch is the point where the least validation loss value happens.
2. Second model has regularization and stop learning at epoch 25(this epoch is the point where the least validation loss value happens.

As I wrote down in the front, key point is that those model record the same least validation loss value

In this case, which model is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used your validation data in the process of training (for selecting hyperparameters) then I highly suggest to have a different set of data as `test-set` and that will give you the answer, otherwise your `validation-set` is actually your `test-set` and when you say they have the same test loss then you mean their performance are the same (if you are not sure if your `test-set` is a good representation of models performance in real life, then make your test-set better, e.g. make it bigger). If you want to use one of them for an important task, I suggest you to have a `cross-validation` test to see which of them is better.

Note that regularization is used for reducing the overfitting in order to achieve higher validation and test results. So after learning and when you want to use the model it really doesn't matter if the model used regularization or not, but the performance and speed matters.

For summary, I see no better model from what you said.

Comment: I think your comment is a proper answer.

Using a test-set for checking which performance is high may be the best way in this situation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have another question.

What is the main effect of using regularization?

Can it make the least validation loss value much less? 

Or dose it make overfitting happen a little bit late?

Comment: L1 or L2 regularization forces the network to have small parameter values. So the network tends to solve the problem in a simple way. when your network has a lot of parameters and not a big enough dataset, it can learn to get better results by memorizing  the inputs and map them to the output, but by normalization you are forcing the network to set additional parameters to zero and learn the concept of the problem. So it really likes to prevent overfitting, not just delaying it. If you omit the regularization you will probabely get better training result but worse validation result

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.

So, based on your answer, if I use regularization, I can get the least validation loss value that is less than before. right?

Comment: If you had overfitting before, **yes** that's right. But if you had no overfitting, that's wrong.

Comment: Ok. Your answer is really helpful for me to understand this thing. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest is go for 2nd model .i.e model with **regularization and stops learning at epoch 25**.

The reason is since you have used regularization technique chances of overfitting your training data is very less.